# How i can redirect from one url to another?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Web is runing using prestashop 1.4 so after upgrade to 1.6 the url is diferent

In prestashop 1.4 i is

```
web.com/category.php?id_category=5980
```

But in prestashop 1.6 i is

```
web.com/index.php?id_category=5980&controller=category
```

So the question is is it possible to use some RewriteRule or another method from mod_rewrite of Apache?

Because when i try tu use in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 ^category.php?id_category=5980 /index.php?id_category=5980&controller=category
```

I got 404 page...

Or may be i need to write some php code for redirect it manualy?

Please advice the right solution.

```
    <FilesMatch "\.tpl$">
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on


#Domain: www.web.com
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Images
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|svg)$">
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404

# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again

# start ~ module watermark section
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond expr "! %{HTTP_REFERER} -strmatch '*://%{HTTP_HOST}*/admin1/*'"
RewriteRule [0-9/]+/[0-9]+\.jpg$ - [F]
</IfModule>
# end ~ module watermark section
```

Comment: Also i fount this: RewriteRule ^category\.php([0-9]*)$ /index.\php$1 [R=301,L] but i dont know how i can add the &controller=category to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule just below `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /sc16/index.php?controller=category [L,QSA,NC,R=301]
```

Due to use `QSA` other query parameter `id_category=5980` will be carried over to new URL.

Comment: using xamp on local machine (http://localhost/sc16/) it redirect me to localhost/

Comment: Yes it there. Whole listing of .htaccess is added to main question.

Comment: @anubhava hi i m facing same type issue. need your help

Comment: Hi, i have this htaccess http://pastebin.com/A1JXKgrb. I want to rewrite my url from http://website.com/preview.php?id=naresh to http://website.com/cv/naresh   and from http://website.com/reume.php?id=naresh to http://website.com/naresh...  but seems i m failed it is not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39387631/rewrite-my-url-remove-query-string-and-make-new-prety-url @anubhava

Answer (score 0):

Another solution i found is this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_category=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^category.php?$ /sc16/index.php?id_category=%1&controller=category [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_product=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^product.php?$ /index.php?id_product=%1&controller=product [R=301,L]
```