# rewrite my url, remove query string and make new pretty url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to rewrite my url from http://website.com/preview.php?id=puzzled to http://website.com/cv/puzzled 
and from http://website.com/resume.php?id=puzzled to http://website.com/puzzled ...  but seems i am failed to get this result.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+) /resume.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^cv/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+) /preview.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^cv/([\w-]+)$ preview.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ resume.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+).php$ $1 [L]
```

From Apache mod_rewrite docs

> The variables SCRIPT_FILENAME and REQUEST_FILENAME contain the same
>   value - the value of the filename field of the internal request_rec
>   structure of the Apache HTTP Server. The first name is the commonly
>   known CGI variable name while the second is the appropriate
>   counterpart of REQUEST_URI (which contains the value of the uri field
>   of request_rec).
>
> If a substitution occurred and the rewriting continues, the value of
>   both variables will be updated accordingly.
>
> If used in per-server context (i.e., before the request is mapped to
>   the filesystem) SCRIPT_FILENAME and REQUEST_FILENAME cannot contain
>   the full local filesystem path since the path is unknown at this stage
>   of processing. Both variables will initially contain the value of
>   REQUEST_URI in that case. In order to obtain the full local filesystem
>   path of the request in per-server context, use an URL-based look-ahead
>   %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} to determine the final value of
>   REQUEST_FILENAME.

Comment: hi with this my login url is not working http://website.com/login.php its 504 here

Comment: how are you putting url for login `website.com/login.php` or `website.com/login`

Comment: i am not adding anything for login.php

Comment: just copy paste yours

Answer (score 1):

You can use these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ resume.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^cv/([\w-]+)/?$ preview.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Try first rule as `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /resume.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Does `resume.php` exist in site root as well as the `.htaccess`?

Comment: Yes. It's on site  root

Comment: yes.. its exist there. i can aceess using url/resume.php?id=myuser

Comment: Did you try: `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /resume.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]` rule?